# iPhone how to turn off animation on leaving a view controller

Tags: iphone, animation, uiviewcontroller

Im wondering how I can turn off the animation of my view controller when leaving back to the parent controller. As I can set the animation property for going to the child controller, I guess there must surely be a way to set the property for the leaving task.

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: How are you going back to the parent controller?  Using dismissModalViewControllerAnimated?

Comment: No I use the pushViewController:.. animated:NO and then to go back I use the built in arrow of the navigation controller!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You have to change the back button behavior.

Create this function in your view controller

```
- (void) popWithoutAnimation {
[self.navigation.controller popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Then change the backBarButtonItem behavior (in your viewDidLoad) :

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.action = @selector(popWithoutAnimation);
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.target = self;
```

Don't care about syntax I'm just giving you the clues to solve your issue